# MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI REST API is not yet supported for this mailbox when accessing me/photos

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

In an Azure AD I gave guest access to a user with an outlook.com account.
Whenever I try to access `graphClient.Me.Photos["48x48"].Content.Request().GetAsync()` I get the MailboxNotEnabledForRESTAPI error.

The code is based on the tutorial from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/aspnet-core?tutorial-step=3

I have removed all references to mailbox and email scopes, yet I still get this error. Why?

Comment: Have you tried it in Graph Explorer or POSTMAN.Do you have any office365 license to this account?

Comment: I believe you're getting this error as the account is MSA account. If you want to call GetPhoto API call, then this operation in version 1.0 supports only a user's work or school mailboxes and not personal mailboxes. Instead of guest user account, try to see if you can repro the issue with work/school account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error as the account is MSA account. If you want to call GetPhoto API call, then this operation in version 1.0 supports only a user's work or school mailboxes and not personal mailboxes. Instead of guest user account, try to see if you can repro the issue with work/school account.